# Cannot use <any> library in c++

Tags: c++, c++17, stdany

### Description

I'm new to c++. My project needs to use any library, which is a new feature after c++ 17. After updating my compiler following [this](https://gist.github.com/application2000/73fd6f4bf1be6600a2cf9f56315a2d91) link. I still encounter an error. Here is the error message and my test code.

### g++ version:

g++ (Ubuntu 6.5.0-2ubuntu1~16.04) 6.5.0 20181026
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

### Code

```
// test_c++17.cc
#include <any>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << "hello c++ 17" << std::endl;
}
```

### Compile

```
gcc -std=c++17 test_c++17.cc -o test
```

### Error Message

[image]

Comment: Try using `g++`

Comment: "I'm new to c++. My project needs to use any library" - IMO there's no project for someone new to C++ where the any library is the right choice.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support

Answer (score 3):

Per cppreference's [C++ compiler support](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) page, `std::any` is not supported until GCC 7.  You will need to upgrade again to a more current version.  Right now 9.2 is the most currently stable release.

Comment: Also libstdc++'s [status page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2017) says the same.

Comment: Problem solved. After updating g++ to a newer version, the code can be compiled. Thanks.